# Display results of SQL query horizontally in multicolumn listbox

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a SQL query that pulls in five columns of information from a table as an array then feeds the results to a Listbox in a tool I've written in Excel with VBA.

Right now it is displaying the results vertically, and I need them to display horizontally. One column in the Listbox should display one column from the SQL table. The listbox properties give it five columns of equal width, and I'm not sure why this isn't working.

```
Sub searchall()
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim list As Object
Set list = SearchForm.Results
Server_Name = "SDL02-VM25"
Database_Name = "PIA"
SQLStr = "select [Agentname],[position],[employeegroup],[supervisor],[manager] from dbo.[HistoricalMasterStaffing] [FirstName] ='" & SearchForm.firstname.value & "' or [LastName] ='" & SearchForm.lastname.value & "' or [Date] = '" & SearchForm.DateSearch.value & "' or [year] = '" & SearchForm.Year.value & "' or [employeegroup] = '" & SearchForm.EmployGroup.value & "' or [position] = '" & SearchForm.Position.value & "' or [ftpt] = '" & SearchForm.PTFT.value & "' or [Contractagency] = '" & SearchForm.Agency.value & "' or [termcode] = '" & SearchForm.TermCode.value & "'
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & vbNullString
rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
With list
Dim arr()
arr() = rs.GetRows
.list = arr()
End With
rs.Close
Cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rs.GetRows` returns the data in a 2-dimensional array with the first index is the field (column) and the second index is the row.
The `listbox.list` expects the data as 2-dimensional array, but with the first index as row, the second as the columns.

So all you have to do is to transpose the data:

```
.list =  Application.Transpose(arr)
```